# How to access a sharepoint site object from an outside farm using powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-farm

like the title says, I am trying to access an spsite (specifically a list on the site collection) from an outside farm through powershell. Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is to use the splist as a guide to do certain commands on a farm that is different than the one where the splist is based and then update the list based on the results of the commands I am running all using powershell. My best guess would be to use psremoting? but im not entirely sure how that would work or if it even would. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

PSRemoting is going to be your only option to execute commands and you will need a vpn tunnel to connect to that outside server, otherwise your powershell scripts have to be run on the server where you are trying to make changes or view data. If you need to update a list with data you can use a CSV file, but if it is on another network you are going to have to have some way to transfer the file to server then maybe have a scheduled task run to do the import if it was on a weekly basis.